# infinite generator integers from range with step

Tags: python, iterator, generator

I need infinite generator, like:

```python
def zigzag_iterator(current_value, step, max_val):
    direction = 1
    while True:
        if current_value >= max_val:
            direction = -1
        elif current_value <= 0:
            direction = 1
        current_value += step * direction
        if direction == 1:
            current_value = min(current_value, max_val)
        else:
            current_value = max(0, current_value)

        yield current_value
```

For input like:

```
g = zigzag_iterator(current_value=2, step=1, max_val=4)
print(*[next(g) for _ in range(15)])
```

it produce correct sequence:
3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3....
I need first generated value be next of current.

But for: `current_value=0, step=32, max_val=260`
I would like to get: 31, 63, 95, 127, 159, 191, 223, 255, 260, 228, 196 ...

Count from 0 and include `max_val` even is step is smaller (see 255, 260) and then subtract full step... same story when we approaching 0. i.e. ... 51, 19, 0, 31

Comment: I think I understand what you want; that said, how do you expect to pass from 0 to 31 with step = 32 ???

Comment: @Swifty counting from 0 to 31 you got 32 integers, so step = 32

Comment: You add or substract the step to/from the previous value, so you'll pass from 0 to 32!And your logic doesn't hold for 31 to 63.

Comment: @emcek And counting backwards from 260 to 228 you get 33 integers rather than 32 according to your logics. Your expected output makes no sense.

Comment: @emcek And you can't even go from 0 to 1 when the step is 1 in your first example because that would require a step of 2 according to your logics.

Comment: I have no idea how the sequence is defined but take your time to look on the definition of _arithmetic sequence_ and work with initial value `a` and common difference `d`: `range(a+d, t, d)` chain with `range(t, 0, -d)` and `range(0, t, -d)` and use `itertools.repeat` where `t` is the threshold

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine, you just have to slightly change the order of the statements:

```
def zigzag_iterator(current_value, step, max_val):
    direction = 1
    while True:
        current_value += step * direction
        if current_value >= max_val:
            current_value = max_val
            direction = -1
        elif current_value <= 0:
            current_value = 0
            direction = 1
        yield current_value
```

Comment: it produce: 32 64 96 128 160 192 224 256 260 228 196 164...

Comment: It does what you asked, except for the illogical 0 to 31 step!